# Because I .......... a long way from my work, I ........ lots of time going to and from work

Tags: tense-agreement

Because I .......... a long way from my work, I ........ lots of time going to and from work.

A) live/waste

B) lived/have wasted

C) have been living/wasted

D) am living/have been wasting

E) was living/am wasting

Although the answer is **A**, I want to know whether the option **D** is also correct. We can say *"I'm living"* if we are currently living somewhere for a short time. So, can the option **D** be also correct?

Comment: I wouldn't mix simple and perfect tenses without a specific reason (perhaps in context). "am" forms are not necessary because we already know we are talking about time periods by using "live" and "lots of time".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, options A, B and D are grammatical.

> **A:** Because I *live* a long way from work, I *waste* lots of time going to and from work. (present; present)

The speaker currently lives somewhere where he is far from work, and so wastes time getting to work habitually.

> **B:** Because I *lived* a long way from work, I *have wasted* lots of time going to and from work. (past; present perfect)

The speaker used to live somewhere far from his workplace, and is saying that the total time he has wasted commuting to work adds up to *lots of time*.

> **D:** Because I *am living* a long way from work, I *have been wasting* lots of time going to and from work. (present perfect progressive; present perfect progressive)

The speaker stresses that he *currently* lives far from work, and stresses that he *currently* wastes lots of time.

D is definitely grammatical, but if a native speaker were to say it, he'd probably use "I've been" in place of "I have been," just because of how long the verb phrase is.

Comment: Can we use past and present perfect tenses in one sentence?

Comment: Also, there must be one correct answer for this question, but it seems there are three correct options.

Comment: The one correct answer depends on what you want to say, or rather when you want to say it.

Comment: The simple past and simple present tenses can't be used together in this sentence, I believe.